# Is there an efficient way to transfer data within a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to ask if there is any more efficient way to transfer values within a dataframe than entering all the cell locations one-by-one?

For example, in order to convert values from cell (1, 11) to cell (51, 21), we may use the command `df.iloc[51, 21] = df.iloc[1, 11]`. However, if we are converting values from a large number of cells to the other cells (e.g., cell (1:50, 11:20) to cell (51:100, 21:30)), it will be very inefficient to type the command `df.iloc[a, b] = df.iloc[c, d]` for 50*10 times.

In this case, I would like to ask if there is a more efficient method to perform the above transformation. Thanks a lot.

In addition, what if it is a transformation from cell (1:50, 11:20) to cell (101:110, 31:80), where cell (101:110, 31:80) is a transpose of cell (51:100, 21:30)? How should the data transformation be performed in this case? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slices as follows:

```
df.iloc[51:101, 21:31] = df.iloc[1:51, 11:21].values
```

Note that slices in Python are half-open: they include the first index but not the last.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if it is a transformation from cell (1:50, 11:20) to cell (101:110, 31:80), where cell (101:110, 31:80) is a transpose of cell (51:100, 21:30)?

Comment: You should be able to transpose the right hand side with `np.tranpose`.

Comment: But the outcome turns out be NaN, instead of the values inside the original cells. 
The code that I use is df.iloc[101:110, 31:80] = np.transpose(df.iloc[1:50, 11:20]).

Comment: Perhaps add `.transpose()` before the `.values` instead then? I'm not at a computer at the moment so I can't check.